# Will Pascal's law apply to two immiscible liquids that have the same density? In other words, does Pascal's law apply to emulsions?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

As far as I know, immiscible liquids form emulsions when mixed, so will [Pascal's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law) apply to this emulsion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a good approximation yes. Pascal's law won't hold exactly for an emulsion because the interface between the two fluids will have a non-zero [interfacial tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), and there will be  small excess pressure inside the emulsion droplets given by the [well known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_pressure):

$$ \Delta P = \frac{2S}{r} $$

where $S$ is the interfacial tension and $r$ is the radius of the drop. However for most emulsions this will cause only a relatively small pressure difference. For most purposes we can take the pressure as the same everywhere in the fluid.